# Find an example of two measurable functions such that $h \in \mathcal{L_1}(\mathbb{R})$ and $h \notin \mathcal{L_1}(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

This question should be shouldn't be too difficult, but I think that I am having difficulty as to understanding how to do the integration with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Again let $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu = \lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure. Find an example of two measurable functions, $f,h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $h \in \mathcal{L}_1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f \notin \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}) $, such that $f(x) \leq h(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

So initially, I thought that I could set $f=\frac{1}{x}$ and $h=1$, but then to integrate these with respect to the Lebesgue measure... help!

Comment: Well there is no bounded below... ? so you can even take h = 0 and f something that grows fast very in the negative direction... $1$ is not in $L_1$. Integrals with respect to the Lebesgue measure agree with the Riemann measure, when they are Riemann integrable. So integrate as usual.

Comment: Two Riemann integrable functions are also Lebesgue integrable, and in this case the Riemann and Lebesgue integral coincide. You can therefore just compute the Riemann integral.

Comment: Okay so I can just integrate to get $\int f d\lambda = ln x$ and $\int h d\lambda = x$. Is the domain not disagreeable in this case as it is the whole of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Take $h=0$ and $f=-1$.  Then $h \in \mathcal{L}_1(\mathbb{R})$  and $f \notin \mathcal{L}_1(\mathbb{R}) $ (because $\int f d\lambda = -\infty$).